# load spring context

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I use intelliJ Idea 10.5. when i use context-param for for spring context and run project Tomcat show me blank page!! when I disable it, page show!

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:context/applicationContext-dao.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable log4j and see the exception Spring is throwing when you start tomcat.. Also make sure that the context file is in the war file (on the location - WEB-INF/classes/context/applicationContext-dao.xml

Ian.